# How to consume an Apache CXF JAX-RS Client WebService

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, cxf

They say [here](http://thetechiehouse.blogspot.in/2012/10/cxf-as-rest-client.html) that there are 3 approaches to build a rest client in apache cxf

My question is:

1) Iam following first approach - Injecting proxies, Did i missed anything ?

2)  How to consume a jax-rs webservice (security signed certificate) by using apache cxf spring configuration?

Webservice url :

```
 http://localhost:8080/services/userSvc/getUserInfo?param1=value1&param2=value2"
```

UserInfoSvc.java:

```
   // What code should be written here
```

application-context.xml :

```
  <jaxrs:client id="restClient"
     address="http://localhost:8080/services/userSvc/getUserInfo"
     serviceClass="com.example.client.UserInfoSvc"
     inheritHeaders="true">
     <jaxrs:headers>
         <entry key="Accept" value="text/json"/>
     </jaxrs:headers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the http-conduit to specify the certificate for your client in application-context.xml

```
<http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http:tlsClientParameters>
        <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="${ssl.keystorepassword}">
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="${ssl.keystorepassword}"
                file="${ssl.keystorefile}" />
        </sec:keyManagers>
        <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
            <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
        </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
    <http:authorization>
    </http:authorization>
    <http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive" />
</http:conduit>
```

**Note:** in my case http conduit is applied to all the services as I'm using  `name="*.http-conduit"` you can customize to use to sepcifc service or proxy for detail please refer [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-ConfiguringanHTTPConduitfromSpring)

The namespace for http and sec are

```
xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
```